# Can grub switch to long mode?

Tags: x86-64, bootloader, grub2

I'm wondering if I can use grub to switch to long mode then load a 64-bit kernel?  I want grub to switch to long mode, setup page tables so the map one-to-one virtual to physical addresses and setup enough page tables to cover physical memory.

Comment: Looking through the code it seems like it grub is capable of directly booting 64-bit kernels. Look at e.g. grub-code/loader/i386/bsd.c, where e.g. `fill_bsd64_pagetable` is called and `grub_relocator64_boot` is returned. (The pagetable created here does not meet your requirements.)